# Need help iterating through a list of strings in python in reverse, as soon as a string with a number is found, return everything before

Tags: python, list, split

So I'm having a little trouble figuring out how exactly to do this.

I have a list of strings, for example ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK2', 'AS0', 'FJ'] and I want to iterate through the list in reverse, and the first string thats found with a digit, i want to return everything before and including the string.

So for the above example, I'd want it to return ["AS0", "FJ"]. It doesn't necessarily have to be in reverse, that's just the easiest way I've found to do it.

I've so far tried this but to no avail:

```
def example(list):
    stringed = str(list)
    return stringed.split('0' or '1' or '2')[::-1]
```

Edit: Answer from Austin worked perfectly

```
lst = ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK2', 'AS0', 'FJ']

for i, x in enumerate(reversed(lst)):
    if any(y.isdigit() for y in x):
        break

print(lst[len(lst)-i-1:])
# ['AS0', 'FJ']
```

Comment: Which version of Python do you use? `list` objects do not have `.split()` method (at least in Python 3.6).

Comment: your problem statement is clear but you attempt is way off!

Comment: `'0' or '1' or '2'` is always `True`

Comment: @PatrickArtner actually `'0' or '1' or '2' == '0'` ;)

Comment: sorry, i converted the list to a string to try if i could split it, i'll edit the op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `any()` and `isdigit()`. Iterate through list in reverse order and break once we find an element having atleast one digit in it. Use it's index to slice the original list:

```
lst = ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK2', 'AS0', 'FJ']

for i, x in enumerate(reversed(lst)):
    if any(y.isdigit() for y in x):
        break

print(lst[len(lst)-i-1:])
# ['AS0', 'FJ']
```

Comment: `i = next(i for i,item in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if any(char.isdigit() for char in item))`

Comment: thank you, this worked, do you mind explaining what exactly is happening after enumerate?

Comment: @user11039395, using `enumerate`, we iterate through list keeping track of indices. The `if` checks if any of the element iterated contains a digit in it. If so, we are breaking the loop immediately. `i` will hold the index from where we need to slice the list further on.

Comment: thats super cool, i didnt know python could do that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use set intersection to examine if a number is in a string.

```
l =  ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK2', 'AS0', 'FJ']

for i in range(len(l)-1, -1, -1):
    if set('0123456789') & set(l[i]):
        print(l[i:])
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses `re` to avoid looping over the characters in each string.

```py
import re

list =  ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK2', 'AS0', 'FJ']

# Loop over list backwards (list[::-1]) and enumerate each entry
for id, l in enumerate(list[::-1]):
    # If entry l contains a digit
    if re.search(r'\d', l):
        # Print all the values proceeding entry l
        print(list[len(list) - id - 1:])
        # Exit loop now we have the first entry with a number
        break
```

Comment: @Austin Thanks, clumsy me. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
  a = ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK2', 'AS0', 'FJ']

for strs in reversed(a):
    if not strs.isalpha():
        print((a[a.index(strs):]))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach:

```
def tailtildigit(str_list):
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in str_list[-1]) or len(str_list) == 1:
        return [str_list[-1]]
    else:
        return tailtildigit(str_list[:-1]) + [str_list[-1]]
```

The idea is to return the last string if a digit is found, otherwise return the result of the function applied to the shortened by one entry list - plus the last string.

Result:

```
tailtildigit(lst)
# ['AS0', 'FJ']
```

By the way, do you expect the complete list to be returned if *no* string contains any digits? Because that's exactly what Austin's and also my solution do...

```
lst2 = ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK', 'AS', 'FJ']
tailtildigit(lst2)
# ['HU', 'ASDF', 'AK', 'AS', 'FJ']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
myList = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

i = len(myList) - 1
while i >= 0:
    if myList[i] == "5": # <-- the number im looking for
        print(myList[i:len(myList)])
    i-=1
```

It returns ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

Comment: OP asked about a list of strings, not ints.